# Tooltip covering bar in highchart

Tags: highcharts

How can I avoid that the tooltip in Highcharts covers the whole bar?
I'm trying to create bar chart with drill-down functionality, but the bar for "John" in the example below i always covered by the tooltip itself, which makes drilldown very difficult.

http://jsfiddle.net/3XZwV/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Column chart with negative values'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [-1, -1, -1, -1, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are interested, you can do it a couple of ways.

### Fix the position of tooltip

Fix the position of your tooltip, using [***`tooltip positioner`***](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner) .

```
        tooltip: {
        positioner: function () {
            return { x: 80, y: 50 };
        }
```

A working example is [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/3XZwV/1/).

### Using followPointer

Using the follow pointer option. You can avoid the problem you are facing and allow the tooltip to be still floating.

```
tooltip:{
            followPointer:true
        },
```

Another working example is [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/3XZwV/2/).

Comment: Yes, I've seen that option, but I would much rather have a floating tooltip if its possible...

Comment: @Bjorn: Updated my answer, check if it meets your requirement.

Comment: Didn't know about the followPointer setting...seems like that should be the default!